# Android app not asking for Billing permission

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, android-permissions, android-billing

I got everything set up for in-app purchase on my application, and I made sure to have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

When installing the Signed APK exported from Eclipse IDE, **Android does not ask for the billing permission in all my permissions request list**.

The application install and run without problems, but my in-app store does not work.
Any help will be appreciated

EDIT

The wiered thing here is that android is not showing the Google play service billing permission among the other permissions right before installing the application. I tested on other device and the permission is there. The device, where the permission, is not showing is Galaxy Tab2 (GT-P5100) with android 4.0.4 .

Comment: Post your logcat or what error you are getting please.

Comment: I am not getting to the errors yet, 
The wiered thing here is that android is not showing the Google play service billing permission among the other permissions right before installing the application. I tested on other device and the permission is there. The device, where the permission, is not showing is Galaxy Tab2 (GT-P5100) with android 4.0.4 .

Comment: Is your google play services installed on your phone up to date?And have you uploaded your apk to google play store as alpha tester, without uploading you won't be able to see in app purchases.